# Who were Krall's men in Star Trek: Beyond?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

I watched Star Trek: Beyond and I can't get my head around one thing:

Spoiler:

> If only a few crew members of Krall survived, who were all the people who flew the spaceships/bees?     Were they the crew of the one survivor that lead Captain Kirk to the planet/dust, but why would they be warriors of Krall who abducted them?     Or were they descendents of the few survivors?

Comment: Related: [Who were the faceless mooks?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57166/49)

Comment: Thank you. I totally missed that sentence. That could be the answer I was looking for, but it isn't verified, is it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The quote from the movie is that the planet that Krall/Edison crash-landed on contained a "drone workforce", presumably some sort of (biological?) robots which would explain the sheer *quantity* of men and ships at his disposal.

> **Edison:** *The indigenous race abandoned this planet long ago. They left behind
> sophisticated mining equipment and a **drone workforce***

That being said, we see several different species ***without their helmets on***. I think we can assume that since he's not stuck on the planet that he was also recruiting from other nearby races that hate the Federation.

[image]

---

As to who was flying the ships, they appear to be controlled by the drones, following the orders of the small number of actual biological pilots.

> **Spock:** *Captain, the flight patterns of bees are determined by individual
> decisions. Krall's swarm formations are too complex not to rely on
> some sort of unified [cyberpathic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cyberpathy) coordination.*

---

This has now been confirmed in an interview with director Justin Lin and screenwriter Simon Pegg

> *"That's what the swarm is – sophisticated mining equipment. **All those soldiers were just worker drones. Krall turned them into an army**, and
> turned the swarm into a weapon. There's all this great backstory to be
> explored in the novelisation!”*"
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek Beyond: 12 things we learnt from Justin Lin and Simon Pegg](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/star-trek-beyond-justin-lin-simon-pegg/)</sup></sub>

Comment: why do these comments (the quote and the several drone species) remind me of the borg?

Comment: Expendable robotic workforce? Sounds like Mudd's World to me.

Comment: @Thomas At first, I thought they were some kind of Borg/Klingons mix judging by the look of them. Perhaps this is some forecast on the next movie...

Comment: @minhundje rumors are exiting already about borg and the next film but we will have to see as there is not even a script currently

Comment: @Thomas : The initial rumour regarding *Beyond* was that it would involve the a full-out war with the Klingons.  Based on that, I have no faith about the Borg being in the next film.

Comment: @praxis like I said as long as no script exists I'm not giving even a cent on rumors.